# hadoop fs –put Unknown command

Tags: hadoop, command, put

Created a folder `[LOAN_DATA]` with below command

```
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://masterNode:8020/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/LOAN_DATA
```

Now using the web UI when I list the contents of directory `/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs`, it shows `LOAN_DATA`.

But when I want to store some Data from a TXT file to the `LOAN_DATA` directory using `put` or `copyFromLocal` I get

**put: Unknown command**

Command used:

```
hadoop fs –put '/home/hadoop/my_work/Acquisition_2012Q1.txt' hdfs://masterNode:8020/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/LOAN_DATA
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 12):

This issue may occur when you copy-paste a command and use it. It is because of the change in font (or character set) used in the document from where it was copied.

For example:

If you copy/paste and execute the command -

`hdfs dfs -put workflow.xml /testfile/workflow.xml`

You may get-

```
–put: Unknown command
```

OR

```
–p-t: Unknown command
```

This happens because the copy is done from a UTF-8 file and the `-` or `u` (or any of the characters) copied may be of different character set.

So just **type the command on the terminal** (don't copy/paste) and you should be fine.

> Alternatively, if you are running a shell script which was copied from
>   some other editor then run a `dos2unix` on the script before running it
>   on the Linux terminal.
>
> Eg: `dos2unix <shell_script.sh>`

Answer (score 4):

Tried your command and "it appears", there is a typo error in the above command 'hadoop fs –put ....'.

Instead of '–put', use '-put' or '-copyFromLocal'. Problem is with '–' but the correct character should be '-'. As such, the error is obvious :-)

Here is my example (using a get command instead of put):

```
$ hadoop fs –get /tmp/hadoop-data/output/* /tmp/hadoop-data/output/
 –get: Unknown command
$ hadoop fs -get /tmp/hadoop-data/output/* /tmp/hadoop-data/output/
 get: `/tmp/hadoop-data/output/part-r-00000': File exists
```

Answer (score 2):

Anand's answer is, of course, correct. But it might not have been a typo but rather a subtle trap. Often when people are learning new technology, they copy and paste commands from websites and blogs. Often, what was originally entered as a dash will be copied as a hyphen. Hyphens differ from dashes only in that they are a tad longer, so the mistake is hard to spot, but since they are a completely different character the command is wrong, that is, "not found".